# Number of Fibonacci numbers up to x

Tags: nt.number-theory

For a large number x>0, how many Fibonacci numbers are there in the interval [1,x]? I have saw the corresponding results in certain places but I have forgotten now. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: If you know that $F_n=a\omega^n+b\omega^{-n}$ with $a,b$ constant and $\omega=(1+\sqrt5)/2$, you can conclude.

Comment: Very closely related problem - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39124/fibonacci-sequence-inversion

Comment: I think this question should be closed, because the first hit on Google for "Fibonacci number" gives you the answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio

Answer (score 6):

Let $G:=(1+\sqrt{5})/2;g:=(1-\sqrt{5})/2$, then the $n$-th Fibonacci number is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(G^n-g^n)$. Note that $|g|<1$. Hence the number of Fibonacci numbers $\le x$ is  $\frac{\log \sqrt{5}x}{\log G}$ plus or minus 1 (and it is easy to see when you need to add or subtract 1).

Comment: @Mark - Don't you mean `$\frac{\log \sqrt{5} x}{\log G}$` ?

Comment: @Moshe: Yes, of course. When I first typed the answer, I denoted $G$ by $g$ and $g$ by $G$, but then I decided that $g$ cannot be bigger than $G$, so I switched the notation, but not everywhere.